# How do I convert a file into a JSON Object in SwiftyJson

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swifty-json

I am trying to import Json data from a user uploaded txt file  into a standard object that I can use via SwiftyJson framework

Here is the contents of the text fie:

```
{
  "String": "answer",
  "String2": "answer2"
}
```

I have successfully read it and turned it into a String file using:

> let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
>           let arrayOfExtensions = ["txt"]
>           openPanel.allowedFileTypes = arrayOfExtensions
>           let result = openPanel.runModal()
>
> ```
>     if result == NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton {
>         return
>     }
>     let fileUrl = openPanel.URL
>
>     do {
>         let stringResult = try String(contentsOfURL: fileUrl!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
>         print (stringResult)
>
>         completionhandler(retrievedData: stringResult, error: nil)
> ```

I am trying to convert this into a JSON object using:

> `let jsonFile = JSON(contentsOfFile)`

The problem is that the resulting JSON object created appears to be blank for all the fields except rawvalue.

Here is the screenshot from the debug console. 
[image]

How to I sucessfully read in the string from the file and then make it populate via SwiftJson correctly?

Comment: Is it possible those properties are `lazy`?

Comment: I don't think so- i cant access them at run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem above was that I was using the wrong method to parse it into JSON.

SwiftyJSON seems to be badly documented hence others had a similar problem.

The correct way to do this is to use :

```
let jsonFile = JSON.parse(string:contentsOfFile)
```